# how to create a reverse proxy in golang

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, net-http

I wants to make a reverse proxy in golang using net package from stl library. Used httputil for creating reverse proxy. But when I make request to the proxy server it return 404 error.

Here is the proxy server code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    demoUrl , err := url.Parse("http://localhost:1000/run/")
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(demoUrl)
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(rw, r)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":2000", nil)
}
```

Here is the origin server code :

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/run", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        w.Write([]byte("I am running"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":1000", nil)
}
```

Please tell what I am missing here and how to fix the bug! Please

Answer (score 1):

The router doesn't match.
this will be working as expected.

```golang
...
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/run/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        w.Write([]byte("I am running"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":1000", nil)
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a silly typo by my side.